# Database designing 2 products having different delivery time

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Hello there i am  trying to build one database for a online store my problem definition is 
an order can contains many items with different delivery dates **for example 1 book will take 2 days to deliver another take 4-5 days to deliver.**

I have a Product table which contains  product delivery time like 2-3 working days or 4-5 working days

In my delivery table how am i going to depict this because it contains 1 order id i can show the user the upper limit time like 5 days for the delivery but  how can i show the back end user 2 different order timings and status of 1 order

How can i show them into my delivery table as they are one order but having different delivery times..

Comment: The common practice is just to show just an item which will take longest to deliver ("your **delivery** will be ready in ...."). This still feels more like a design thing than programming, but when you want to show "delivery time" for each item you probably could use `datediff` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Comment: That's true in case for customer but if i want back end user to see it how can i specify that .

Answer (score 1):

It's a 1:1 relationship between items and delivery dates.  Either make the foreign key relationship between your ITEM and DELIVERY tables or add a DELIVERY_DATE column to the ITEM table.

The difficulty comes when you think the relationship is between order and delivery date.

You need a way to roll up all the items in the order to come up with an overall delivery date.  You might want to give users the ability to drill down to see the details, item by item.

Answer (score 1):

You maybe can do query like this:

```php
$rowset = $db->fetch_all( 'SELECT ... FROM orders
    INNER JOIN products ON ...
    INNER JOIN delivery ON ...
    ORDER BY products.id, delivery.date
    WHERE ...');
```

This will cause that you'll have record/row for each delivery date entry (you can group them by date then or do something similar).

And then browse them all by code like this:

```php
$productID = 0;
foreach( $rowset as $row){
    if( $productID == $row.productId){
        // Code for multiple dates
    } else {
        // Code for new item
    }
    $productID = $row.productId
}
```

Does this fit?